# Opening a text file is passed as a command line parameter

Tags: c#, command-line, console-application

I need Console Application in C# which may open a .txt file like a parameter.
I know only  how to open a .txt file from root.

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(@"Input.txt");
Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: You say *write it for me*?

Comment: [System.IO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.io.aspx)?

Comment: sorry about straightness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point. Then what you want to do with the contents of the file is up to you

```
using System.IO;    // <- required for File and StreamReader classes

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if(args != null && args.Length > 0)
    {
        if(File.Exists(args[0]))
        {
            using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(args[0]))
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                ........
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the above approach reads one line at a time to process the minimal quantity of text, however, if the file size is not a concert you could avoid the StreamReader object and use

```
        if(File.Exists(args[0]))
        {
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);
            foreach(string line in lines)
            {
                 ... process the current line
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can i choose required file?

Comment: You pass the filename as an argument on startup of your application like: `yourApp.exe yourfilename.txt`. If you want to ask the user for a filename while the app is already running, look into [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.console.readline.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but, where I must to put my .txt file?

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main(string[] args)
{    
  if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
  {
   //Check file exists
   if (File.Exists(args[0])
   {
    string Text = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
   }

  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic console aplication :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

The parameter args of the method Main is what you need, when you launch your program from a console you type in your program name and next to it your parameter( here the path to the txt file)
Then to get it from the program just get it by args the first parameter is args[0] .

I hope it will help you

Comment: +1 because this is *exactly* what OP requested. A console application in C# which may (or may not) open a .txt. ^_^