# Doubleclick on saved file open my windows form but don't pick up any saved data

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, openfiledialog, savefiledialog

I created simple program for save/open practice. Made a setup and associated my program with my own datatype, called it .xxx (for practice).

I managed to **Save** and **Open** code and data from textbox but **only** from my program. **Double click** (or enter from windows-desktop) **open up my WindowsForm as it is but there is an empty textbox.** I want my saved file to be opened on double click in the same condition as when I open it from my program. How to set that up??

*Here is the code of simple app (cant post images but it simple - got 1 label and 1 textbox with open and save buttons):*

```
private void ButOpen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string data = Read(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                textBox1.Text = data;
            }
            else
            {//do nothing }     
        }    
private string Read(string file)
        {

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
            string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();

            return data;
        }    
private void ButSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Something|*.xxx";

            DialogResult result = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

            string file = saveFileDialog1.FileName.ToString();
            string data = textBox1.Text;
            Save(file, data);
        }
private void Save(string file, string data)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file);
            writer.Write(data);
            writer.Close();
        }
```

**NOTE:**

**My similar question was marked as duplicate but it is not, and this question which was referenced as duplicate  [Opening a text file is passed as a command line parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710152/opening-a-text-file-is-passed-as-a-command-line-parameter) does not help me.It's not the same thing...**

Just wanted to find out how to configure registry so windows understand and load data inside the file, or to file save data somehow so i can open it with double click.

So someone please help. If something is not clear I will give detailed information just ask on what point.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try simply right click on the file type and set your program as the default application for opening that file type? Also the question you referenced was closed as not a real question not because it was a duplicate. I'm sure you will find wonderful material with a simple Google search. :)

Comment: Your code is a missing the load from command line part the duplicate has. So why do you expect it to work?

Comment: I associated my program with this file type as default in installer...

@CodeInChaos sorry I am a noob and that is why I am asking becouse Idont know what part is missing

Comment: @CodesInChaos can you please tell me what kind of command should I use? and what way? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has some information about this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166549.aspx

Basically you need to create an entry in the registry so that explorer.exe knows to launch your program when that file is activated (e.g. double-clicked).

Explorer will then pass the path to the file as an argument to your program.

Comment: well... i kinda understand that but i don't know what else to do... in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT i have my extension defined as **.xxx (Data is Something) - Something (Value not set) - ShellNew (Value not set)** ...

And down i got my data for **Something - shell - open - command (and my command default data value is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tryout\TestProgram.exe" "%1""**

Comment: You may need to terminate explorer.exe and relaunch it / reboot the computer as changes to the registry aren't immediately applied.

Comment: @dodoria1992 not sure what to offer other than advice to ensure you're using the registry correctly. It can be tricky to get right.

Comment: yes I know, that's why I am trying here to find an answer.. thank you for your time and advice